# QR code tracking on Android with MRTK3: IL2CPPLinkage error when building library

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mrtk

Unity Building Library failed, IL2CPPLinkage error, with MRTK3 and QR Code Tracking on Android

I tried to track a QR code with MRTK 3 and Andriod.
 [have used this attachment](https://localjoost.github.io/MRTK2-to-MRTK3-migrating-the-QRCode-sample/)

The following error occurs when building on Android:

```
Building Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\d8kzr\libil2cpp.so failed with output:
Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/soo2_.QR.DotNet.o: In function `IL2CPPLinkage_WindowsGetStringRawBuffer_m43E89486907592139AB0D52752B2D8D483E4FEE6':
H:/projects/**/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Microsoft.MixedReality.QR.DotNet.cpp:1395: undefined reference to `WindowsGetStringRawBuffer'
H:/projects/**/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Microsoft.MixedReality.QR.DotNet.cpp:1395: undefined reference to `WindowsGetStringRawBuffer'
Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/soo2_.QR.DotNet.o: In function `IL2CPPLinkage_WindowsDeleteString_m8175860EEA9E79F2F530A1EC165CE65FDD475933':
H:/projects/**/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Microsoft.MixedReality.QR.DotNet.cpp:1405: undefined reference to `WindowsDeleteString'
H:/projects/**/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Microsoft.MixedReality.QR.DotNet.cpp:1405: undefined reference to `WindowsDeleteString'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
UnityEditor.GenericMenu:CatchMenu (object,string[],int)
```

I have tried the following to fix the error:

- [DllImport("__Internal")] Metodes removed from IL2CPPLinkage class in the Platform.cs file
- Search for "WindowsGetStringRawBuffer_m43E89486907592139AB0D52752B2D8D483E4FEE6" in the build output, but nothing found